# Factorial space complexity

Tags: factorial, space-complexity

I just had a quick question about space complexity. I'm new to algorithms, and I was listening to a discussion about algorithms with different space complexities, and I was attempting to think of examples on the higher end of the spectrum. What would be an example of an algorithm with an O(n!) space complexity, and how would one improve on that constraint?

Comment: Permutation of n symbols.

Comment: Ah, so if we had a function like foo(n), where n was a list of permutations of something like the string 'red', the space complexity of that would be n!?